# Column won't Bind

Tags: sql-server

I have the following statement as the first step in a Stored procedure

```
As
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
  DELETE DB1.dbo.Members WHERE DB1.dbo.members.ID = DB2.dbo.in_table.ID
  --after the delete I will insert all of the new data from in_table to Members
END
```

DB2.dbo.in_table.ID won't bind.  The stored procedure is set to be stored on DB2.
DB1 locations bind perfectly.  Is it a database permission issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not referencing or JOINing the second table anywhere in your query:

```
DELETE 
FROM DB1.dbo.Members 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ID 
                FROM DB2.dbo.in_table 
                WHERE DB1.dbo.Members.id = B2.dbo.in_table.ID)
```